# How do I write a float value from within a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows

I've tried using memset but it seems to only replace the code completely. How do I go about this? Here's my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "memory.h"

DWORD paranoid = sigScan("\xFF\x15\xE0\x11\x00\x01\xFF\x15\xDC\x11\x00\x01","xxxxxxxxxxxx");

void initiate() {
    if (paranoid) {
        std::cout<<"Paranoid: "<<paranoid<<std::endl;
        // i need to make the DWORD address returned by sigScan have a float value of -1
    } else {
        MessageBoxA(GetActiveWindow(),"Error: sigscan failed (paranoid)","Error",0);
    }
}
```

Comment: DWORD is 32 bits and a pointer may be 64 bits. There's no such thing as a "DWORD address". This is suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, but if I understand you right then this will work

```
*(float*)paranoid = -1;
```

If I haven't understood you right, then this will probably crash your program.